# Is there a way to remove shellac or varish from a wood sign with painted lettering without runinig the letters?

Tags: wood

I have a wood sign from the 1950's that has red and blue letters painted on it. It is a grey piece of drift wood. Someone either used shellac or varnish on it about 8 years ago and the sign looks glossy and dark on the side with the lettering but lighter and natural on the back where there is no lettering.

Is there a way to remove the shellac or varnish without ruining the lettering?

Comment: I don't have time to write up a full answer right now, but I'd probably try a chemical stripper first.  They're fairly nasty to work with but effective on most finishes, and they don't require a lot of mechanical force on the piece.

Comment: I agree with SaSSaFraS1232 generally, but if it's 1950's, you might try alcohol or even paint thinner first as Shellac is easy to strip with those.  Those won't touch a poly finish.  Moving up if necessary, strippers also come in that more safer to more effective path, and until you need a bigger hammer, you might save a few brain cells dying from the really toxic stuff.

Comment: You'll only be able to reliably remove the glossy layer if this is shellacked. If varnish was used there's basically no way [for you] to get it off without damaging the paint underneath, regardless of the varnish used.